# Is there a way to turn off page-at-a-time scrolling animation in Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate2

Textmate 2 animates scrolling when using PageUp/PageDown keys. This against the Human Interface Guidelines, and it is sloooooooow.

Anyone know how to turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the scrolling behavior via:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool NO
```

To turn it on again:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool YES
```

Make sure to restart Textmate after setting those values.